# Why does 'file.size' take a lot of time, and how to reduce the time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, html5-filesystem

I am making an app that deals with songs being dragged to the app. When I use the `file.size` to get the size of the file it takes approx 1500ms (avg) to get this value. Is there any faster way? I understand why it takes time (and memory) but since I am new to dealing with files in HTML5, maybe there is something that I don't know of which can make the process faster.

The same stands true for the file system API. If I call in the file through it and call for `file.size`, it takes similar time.

PS I got to this conclusion by adding `console.time()` in my code.

Here is the code (massively stripped down)

```
fileSystem.root.getFile(id, {}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(audioTemp) {
        console.time(1);
        console.log(audioTemp.size);
        console.timeEnd(1)
    });
});
```

This is the file system API example. This (obviously) needs the file named `id` to be there for it to work. Below is the D&D file input code

```
function onChangeAddSongsInput() {
    var files = document.getElementById('addSongsInput').files;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        console.time(1);
        console.log(files[i].size);
        console.timeEnd(1)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I am on an AMD equiv of core two duo, 2.7 GHz, 2 gigs of ram, win7 x64. The specs i believe are actually decent enough. So if something does take long enough on my machine i will take it as a no-go.

This is a blocker for a major bug fix in my app. I would really like to ship the with a fix for this long time included. I cannot set a bounty (yet) maybe there is a minimum time before a bounty is set.

**EDIT**

I did some testing and as it turns out, it takes so long because chrome *calculates*  the size instead of just reading it from some metadata. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmqT7.png) is the test result.

The bigger the file, the longer it takes and if called second time it uses some cache and does not load the file. So now.. how can i reduce this time? Size is an important info in my app but probably not important enough to slow user's upload rate by about 1.5 seconds for every file! I am planning on importing libraries and it would really help to reduce this time when adding 100 or so songs. This time then will be a major bump to app's response time.

Comment: code you post a code sample or make a fiddle on JSFiddle.net please ?

Comment: sure :) i thought it was easy enough but well, never mind.

Comment: I just wanted to see how your code works on my hardware is all :)

Comment: no probs :D added the code :)

Comment: What browser/OS/Size of file are you working with ? it's pretty fast here with an average size mp3.

Comment: well its a chrome dev/win7 (64)/5-7 mb mp3. I am curious, what are the numbers that you are getting? are they like 1500ms or alot lower?

Comment: I tested with a 5.2Mb MP4 and it came in around 640ms. It's still slower then I'd expect but not unreasonable really. Let me test something else though, I've just had a thought ...

Comment: maybe its because of the processor? i am on AMD equiv of core two duo. If you are on i3 or even i7(!) the result might be different. just a thought :O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quasi-educated guess:

Looking at [the definition of the HTML5 `File` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-FileAPI-20091117/#dfn-file) shows that a `File` is a `Blob` and that the `size` attribute is actually part of the [`Blob` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-FileAPI-20091117/#dfn-Blob).

Since a `Blob` is an abstraction over a raw chunk of data, accessing the `size` attribute might actually cause the implementation to load the whole file into memory.  You could write an experiment to see if the delay varies with the size of the file or if the delay only occurs on the first read of the `size` attribute.

*EDIT*:

I really feel like this inefficiency is a problem with the browser's implementation of the `File` interface, but here're two workaround ideas about how to avoid latency when loading large files into memory:

**Web workers**([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers), [WHATWG Webapps Standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers)) would allow you to put the slow loading of the files essentially into another thread.  This, I think, is your best bet.

Another approach would be to use the [`slice` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-FileAPI-20091117/#dfn-slice) of the `Blob` interface to load up small portions of the `File`.  If the implementation of `slice` only loads the needed portion of the file, it should go faster. You'll have to load multiple slices for every file and you'll need to detect when you get to the end of a file by paying attention to the size of the `Blob` returned by `slice`.  You'll detect the end of the file by getting back a blob smaller than you expected-- from the spec:

> The slice method MUST clamp on values of size if index arithmetic exceeds the bounds of size. In particular, this means that for a given slice call:
>
> If start + length > size then a user agent MUST return a Blob object as if slice(start, size-start) was called.
>
> If start > size then a user agent MUST return a Blob object of size 0

Unfortunately, the spec also mentions the possibility of throwing exceptions when you request a slice outside of a `Blob`'s buffer size-- on any implementations that do that, you'll have to catch an exception to detect the end of file.

Comment: hmm yes i was almost certain that the whole file is first loaded into the memory and then the size is calculated.. The reason (i think) is that the size of a file is not just any metadata which can be read, it has to be * calculated*. I will write those two tests anyways to confirm the point. The question for now is that is there any metadata that that can be read quicker than loading the file to memory and then calculating the size

Comment: Alright done with testing here is the result http://twitpic.com/6iyb39 I tried multiple times with doffrent files, same result every time. The bigger the file, the longer it takes and if called second time it uses some cache and does not load the file. So now.. how can i reduce this time? Size is an important info in my app but probably not important enough to slow user's upload rate by about 1.5 seconds for *every* file! I am planning on importing libraries and it would really help to reduce this time when adding 100 or so songs.

Comment: I added two possible workarounds to my answer-- I think they are your best bet.  This undesirable behavior of `File.size` should probably be filed as a bug as well, if you have the time to write it up well.

Comment: the slice implementation seems a bitof a hack really, i think i will go the web workers way. But will have to run some tests to find if writing a worker actually be worth all the extra code. I am theoretically familiar with workers and AFAIK workers offload the heavy work to CPU.. right? If yes then it *can* have a good enough reduction. But i will post back after doing some tests. Thanks a lot for pointing me to it! :D also where should i file the bug? webkit or chromium?

Comment: well no i am on win, but i think i will add it to chromium and they will add it upstream if they feel the need to do so. :)

Comment: ok so i have decided to stick to web workers. I will run some tests and post the results in the question :D thanks a ton!

Answer (score -3):

if you increase the time set under Console.Time(), it will givw you more performance. You need to make sure that this time is not timing out till the file is being loaded and displayed.

Comment: `increase the time set under Console.Time()` can you elaborate? and i dont think the delay is because file hasn't loaded into the browser because it takes similar time when there are multiple files dragged and the `.size` happens in a loop.

Comment: I was telling to keep the waiting time and sleep time more in the respective places of file loading